# Change backslashes to double backslashes

Tags: batch-file

Hi I have files in dirs and subdirs, Id'd like to have it in this format

`"file:///c:\\test\\subdir\\lastdir\\file.jpg","lastdir"`

I'm stuck in replacing the `\` with `\\`

what I have made so far is:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@echo off
echo {
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /s /b /a-d') do (
    for %%I in ("%%~dpF.") do (
    set a = "%%F"
    echo !a!----------------------------this gives me echo disabled
    echo "file:///"%%F","%%~nxI",
    )
)
echo }
pause
```

I thought to use

```
set a=%%F
set a=%a:\=/%
echo %a%
```

but this does not work even with `!a!`

Comment: Spaces are significant in batch, so your line `set a = "%%F"` is creating a variable called `%a %`. Remove the spaces on either side of the equals sign. I don't know if your code has any other issues, but that's why `%a%` is reporting no value.

Comment: How does " I'm stuck in replacing the \ with \\" go with `set a=%a:\=/%` (besides it should be `set a=!a:\=/!`?

Comment: SomethingDark, Stephan: yes and yes, now the script works thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this, `"file:///c:/test/subdir/lastdir","file.jpg"`, what you're trying to achieve?

```bat
@SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
@(  Echo {
    For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B/S/A-D 2^>NUL') Do @(
        Set "_=%%~dpG"
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        Set "_=!_:~,-1!"
        Echo    "file:///!_:\=/!","%%~nxG"
        EndLocal
    )
    Echo }
) > "output.txt"
```

If you really do want that strange non file URI type output, `"file:///c:\\test\\subdir\\lastdir\\file.jpg","lastdir"`, then:

```bat
@SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
@(  Echo {
    For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B/S/A-D 2^>NUL') Do @(
        Set "_=%%~dpG"
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        For %%H In ("!_:~,-1!") Do @Echo   "file:///!_:\=\\!%%~nxG","%%~nxH"
        EndLocal
    )
    Echo }
) > "output.txt"
```

---

Just change the `output.txt` file on the last line to the name you require. *(If you really want that to the cmd.exe window, simply replace `"output.txt"` with `CON`)*

Comment: YES! I wanted that strange non file URI type output, I'll study that code, I must learn a lot! thanks!!!